# Android App connecting to JSP page

Tags: java, android, mysql, jsp

I am trying to connect my Android App to a JSP page, to get  data from a database on the same server. My web page is working fine, here you can see the code:

associazioni.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSetMetaData" %>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%
try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    // crea un collegamento con il database "csv"
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/csv", "username", "password");
    Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
    // esegue la query di selezione
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM associazioni");

    // scrive che tutto è andato a buon fine
    out.println("OK");

    // scrive i dati
    while (rs.next()) {
        // id_associazione
        out.println(rs.getString(1));
        // nome
        out.println(rs.getString(2));
        // indirizzo
        out.println(rs.getString(3));
        // telefono
        out.println(rs.getString(4));
        // contatti
        out.println(rs.getString(5));
        // descrizione
        out.println(rs.getString(6));
    }

    // scrive che il processo è concluso
    out.println("END");

    // chiude la connessione
    stat.close();
    conn.close();

// cattura le eccezioni
} catch (Exception e) {
    // scrive il tipo di eccezione
    out.println(e.toString());
}
%>
```

As you can prove yourself, if you go to:
http://liceocuneoweb2.linuxd.org:8080/CSV/associazioni.jsp
the web page is working, writing "OK" at the beginning and "END" at the end of the file.
The problems come when I try to access it from the application, I write you down my code, if you can suggest me better ways to write it, or just solve the problem, I will be very grateful!

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView resultsTV;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private String result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        resultsTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.results);
        new RetrieveResults().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void leggi() {
        try {
            ArrayList<String> pagina = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (true) {
                String r = this.reader.readLine();
                if (r.equals("END")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    pagina.add(r);
                }
            }
            scriviResults(pagina);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            resultsTV.setText(e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void scriviResults(ArrayList<String> pagina) {
        for (int i=0; i<pagina.size(); i++) {
            resultsTV.append(pagina.get(i) + "\n");
        }
    }

    private class RetrieveResults extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            collegati();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            if (result.equals("OK")) {
                leggi();
            } else {
                resultsTV.setText("Errore");
            }
        }
    }

    private void collegati() {
        try {
            String link = "http://liceocuneoweb2.linuxd.org:8080/CSV/associazioni.jsp";
            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            result = reader.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            resultsTV.setText(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This program is not working as I wish, it should connect to the server and start reading the lines, if the first String is "OK" then it reads the other untill "END" and put the data in a ArrayList. At the end of the program it prints the Array out via TextView.
Sometimes it gives me "Errore", some other times it cannot connect to the server, it never give back the whole table of the database. I do not know what to try, the code seems correct to me.
Thanks for your time and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Servlet instead of a Servlet Page to generate your response.

Also instead of having a line separated response use the JSON api to create a JSON object or array and map your information to that. Write the JSONObject to your response using the write method. [JSONObject Javadoc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/index.html?org/json/JSONObject.html)

In your MainActivity.java, to retrieve your information use the Java HttpURLConnection to create a HTTP GET request. Once you have the response string parse it into a JSONObject and access the information for further processing. [The example in this link explains how to create a HTTP Connection and send a GET request](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/)

Edit:
Since I don't have a result set I simplified the solution for the servlet.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@WebServlet(name = "JSONResponseExample", urlPatterns = {"/JSONResponseExample"})
public class JSONResponseExample extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        final JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");        

        JSONObject item1 = new JSONObject();
        item1.put("id", "1");
        item1.put("name", "name 1");
        item1.put("email", "Email Adderess 1");
        jsonArray.put(item1);

        JSONObject item2 = new JSONObject();
        item2.put("id", "2");
        item2.put("name", "name 2");
        item2.put("email", "Email Adderess 2");
        jsonArray.put(item2);

        Writer jsonWriter = jsonArray.write(writer);
        jsonWriter.close();
    }
}
```

The response to any GET requests sent to this servlet will be:

```
[
   {
       "id": "1",
       "name": "name 1",
       "email": "Email Address 1"
   },
   {
       "id": "2",
       "name": "name 2",
       "email": "Email Address 2"
   }
]
```

Once you get the String response from the HTTPRequest you can parse it in the following manner:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(responseString);

for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
  JSONObject item = array.get(i);
  String name = item.get("name");
  String email = item.get("email");
  // ... You get the Idea.
}
```

You can download the JSON jar file from any maven repository. 
central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20141113/json-20141113.jar

Comment: Can you please explain better how to use this JSONObject? How can I put table's data in it (all data is String)? How can I response with it from the Servlet and get it back in the Application? Can you write some piece of code? Thanks!!!

Comment: I added some examples, hope they help

Comment: Last thing: to get the responseString should I use the method "getResponseMessage()" of httpURLConnection? `JSONArray array = new JSONArray (con.getResponseMessage());` You are very useful, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The response message simply says if you where able to connect to the server. In the example that I linked to about how to get a HTTP Connection use the logic in the sendGet() method.  At the end of that method there is a System.out.println(response.toString()); . The response.toString() is the JSON string that you need to parse. The response code or response message only tells you if you successfully connected or what the error was. How you handle connection errors is up to you. You could try to reconnect in case of failure.